# What is the buildSessionFactory() method in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

kindly explain the need of this method and use of it?
I am new to hibernate so plz try to answer in simple language and if you can provide some source to your answer that would be great.

Comment: are you clear with idea buildSessionFactory() method,But this metd is depreciated in hibernate 4

Answer (score 1):

This example contains code which you can use in spite of buildSessionFactory ()

```
 private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    private static SessionFactory configureSessionFactory() throws HibernateException {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();        
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        return sessionFactory;
    }
```

Comment: Man I wanted to know the functioning of buildSessionFactory() method,not an alternative.